# Solving the system $a+be^{-\lambda t_i}\cos(wt_i)=\epsilon_i$ (with $i=1,2$) for $\lambda$ and $w$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, nonlinear-system

I have the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align}
a+be^{-\lambda t_1}\cos(wt_1)&=\epsilon_1 \\
a+be^{-\lambda t_2}\cos(wt_2)&=\epsilon_2
\end{align}$$

$a$, $b$, $t_1$, $t_2$, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are given. I need to solve for $\lambda$ and $\omega$ and I know that $\lambda$ and $\omega$ are both real and positive.

How can I solve for those?

I did the following:

$$a+be^{-\lambda t_1}\cos(wt_1)=\epsilon_1\rightarrow\lambda=-\frac{1}{t_1}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\epsilon_1-a}{b}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(wt_1)}\right)$$

So:

$$a+b\exp\left(-\left\{-\frac{1}{t_1}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\epsilon_1-a}{b}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(wt_1)}\right)\right\}t_2\right)\cos(wt_2)=\epsilon_2$$

And only $\omega$ I do not know but I do not know how to solve the last equation.

Comment: Have you given concrete values? Solving this equation explicitely is not possible.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The concrete values are measurement values.